# Solr.xml and schema.xml of embedded solr on Spring Data Solr

Tags: solr, spring-data-solr

I'm confused about uses of `EmbeddedSolrServerFactory`used with Spring Data Solr.
I have a configuration for embed a Solr server:

```
    @Bean(name = "solrServer")
    @ConditionalOnExpression("'${solr.embedded}'=='true'")
    public SolrServer embeddedSolrServer() throws Exception {
         EmbeddedSolrServerFactory factory = new EmbeddedSolrServerFactory(env.getRequiredProperty("solr.home"));
         return factory.getSolrServer();
    }

    @Bean
    public SolrTemplate solrTemplate(SolrServer solrServer) throws Exception {
        return new SolrTemplate(solrServer);
    }
```

I want use embedded Solr if `solr.embedded`property is true. It works as expected, but when it tries to create SolrServer bean I get the following exception:

`Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/ignasi/solr_home/solr.xml (No such file or directory)`

So I guess it means that solr.xml file is needed. Which should be the content of this file? And I will need schema.xml file too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are base Solr configuration files.

solr.xml - https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solr.xml%20%28supported%20through%204.x%29

schema.xml - http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml

You also have solrconfig.xml - http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml

You may download the latest distribution of Solr from http://lucene.apache.org/solr/ and try one of their example configurations to start with. Located under /example directory. It may be easier to start with /example/solr.